# Nothing But JSON Errors, PHP related

Tags: php, json

Anyhow I have messed with this json thing for hours. Like I mean 8+. I just dove into php after having a understanding of html and css. Able to point a buddy where he went wrong. This is actualy the farthest I got... Hardy har har.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
</head>
<?php
// copy file content into a string var
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');

function decodejson(){
    $jd = json_decode($json,true);
    $curated = array();
    foreach($jd(['curated']) as $key => $jd){
        $value = json_decode($jd, true);
        $category = $jd->category;
        $title = $jd->title;
        $brand = $jd->brand;
        $image = $jd->image;
        $author = $jd->author;
        $like = $jd->like;
        $link = $jd->link;
        $price = $jd->price;
    }
    return;
}
?>


<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--START OF ROW-->
  <div class="row">
    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
      <div class="price">
        <h4><?php echo  $jd['price']; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img class="center-block" src="<?php echo  $json['image']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h6><?php echo  $jd['title']; ?></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="brand">
        <h6><?php echo  $json['brand']; ?></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4-4">
        <div class="social-footer">
          <div class="col-4-4 trending">
            <h4>Trending<h4>
    </div>
        <div class="col-4-4 likes">
          <span class="fa fa-heart"><?php echo  $jd['like']; ?><span>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div><!--Product END-->
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON BELOW:

```
{

    "curated": [ 
      { "category": "home",
        "title": "Tosca Umbrella Stand, White",
        "brand": "YAMAZAKI HOME",
        "image": "http://i67.tinypic.com/5bwug3_th.jpg",
        "author": "mysunshineaway",
        "like": "3",
        "link": "http://google.com",
        "price": "82"
      },
            { "category": "home",
        "title": "Tosca Umbrella Stand, White",
        "brand": "YAMAZAKI HOME",
        "image": "http://i67.tinypic.com/5bwug3_th.jpg",
        "author": "mysunshineaway",
        "like": "3",
        "link": "http://google.com",
        "price": "82"
      },
            { "category": "home",
        "title": "Tosca Umbrella Stand, White",
        "brand": "YAMAZAKI HOME",
        "image": "http://i67.tinypic.com/5bwug3_th.jpg",
        "author": "mysunshineaway",
        "like": "3",
        "link": "http://google.com",
        "price": "82"
      }
  ]
  }
```

STYLE BELOW:

```
body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
.row {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tile {
  margin: 30px 30px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tile .price {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
.tile .price h4 {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  position: relative; 
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}
.tile .image img {
  height: 30vh;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  align-content: center
}
.tile .title h6 {
  color: #95a5a6;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.tile .brand h6 {
  color: #95a5a6;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.tile .social-footer {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -4px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.tile .social-footer .trending h4{
  color: #95a5a6;
  padding-top: -5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float:left;
}
.tile .social-footer .likes span {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

/*BOOTSTRAP CENTERING*/
.container-fluid{
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}




@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .tile {
  margin: 30px 30px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
  .tile .image img {
  height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  align-content: center
}
  .tile .social-footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.tile .social-footer .trending h4{
  color: #95a5a6;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float:left;
}
.tile .social-footer .likes span {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 900px){
  .row {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
  .tile {
  margin: 30px 30px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
} 
    .tile .image img {
  height: 60vh;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  align-content: center
}
    .tile .social-footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 34px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.tile .social-footer .trending h4{
  color: #95a5a6;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float:left;
}
.tile .social-footer .likes span {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is. That's kind of important.

Comment: Undefined variable: jd and the second problem is "Illegal string offset 'brand' in /index.php on line 45"" Basiicly what is breaking my progress.

Comment: `jd` is only in scope within the function that it's declared in. Return `jd` from the function, then use the return value.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use a client side variable server side? Where is `$jd` declared?

Comment: I seriously Just hopped on php last night. I understand the basics but still learning. Basicly what I want is to update a json file so it then can post on my template on php and create a grid system. And perferably server side.

Comment: You never call the `decodejson()` function anywhere.

Comment: @JamesAlton You need to return the data from the function, just as in any other language. All the variables you create in `decodejson` are destroyed when the function exits. Put all the data into a class/map, then return that. Then use that returned value inside the `body`.

Comment: @Barmar Can't beleive I didn't see that. Ya, you definitely need to call the function for it to run.

Comment: You also need to pass `$json` as an argument to the function. Functions can't access global variables by default. It sounds like you need to study some PHP tutorials, you're not ready to code yet.

Comment: Ok cool Its mostly fixed. Turns out it was my function. Now its actually showing the json properly. Thanks for helping me with this issue and understanding functions

Comment: The function has lots of other problems. You use the same `$jd` variable for the original decode of the JSON and the `foreach` variable. Then you call `json_decode` again inside the loop, but `$jd` there contains the object in the array, not a JSON string. Each time through the loop you overwrite all the variables, so at the end they'll just contain the values from the last object in the JSON array. But you never use any of those variables.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my functions where all wacked and that I need to hit the books. Thanks for the help Barmar and Carcigenicate

```
function &decodejson(){
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$jd = json_decode( $json, true);
    $curated = array();
     foreach($json(['curated']) as $key => $jso){
         $value = json_decode($jso, true);
        $category = $jso->category;
        $title = $jso->title;
        $brand = $jso->brand;
        $image = $jso->image;
        $author = $jso->author;
        $like = $jso->like;
        $link = $jso->link;
        $price = $jso->price;
        return $jso;
    }

    }
    $jd =& decodejson();
```